# Find a closed formula given by the recurrence.

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find a closed formula for $d_n$, where {$d_n$} is the sequence given by the recurrence:
$d_n = 4d_{n−1} − 4d_{n−2} − 2n$,
and $d_0 = 0, d_1 = 1$.

My attempt: Since this is a e.g.f I multiply everything by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$. What do I do from here?

Comment: It looks like an ordinary generating function would work better to me.  The homogeneous part yields to the characteristic polynomial approach.

Comment: So do I multiply by $x^n$ instead?

Comment: Multiply by $x^n$, sum over $x=2$ to $\infty$, write the expression in terms of $D(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_nx^n$, then solve for $D(x)$. You should get a rational function, which you can use partial fraction decomposition to obtain a few simpler terms of the form e.g. $\frac{c_1}{1-x}$, $\frac{c_2}{(1-x)^2}$, which you can again expand into series. The result is a closed-form for the series $D(x)$, whose coefficient for $x^n$ is the $n{\mathrm{th}}$ term of the sequence, $d_n$.

Comment: I get the summation of $-2nx^n$. How do I simplify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have,
$$\theta_n = 4\theta_{n-1} - 4\theta_{n-2} - 2n\ \ \forall \ n>1 $$
$$\theta_0=0,\theta_1=1$$

let,
$$\alpha_n = \theta_n - 2\theta_{n-1}\ \ \forall n\ge1$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \ \alpha_n=2\alpha_{n-1}-2n\ \ \forall n\gt1\ \ \&\  \alpha_1=1 $$
which can be solved to get,
$$\alpha_n = 2(n+2)\ -\ 5\cdot2^{n-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \ \theta_n = 2\theta_{n-1}\ +\ 2(n+2)\ -\ 5\cdot2^{n-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \ \theta_n = (16-5n)\cdot2^{n-1}\ -\ 2(n+4)$$

**PS:** Both recurrences are of the form $\ t_n=2\cdot t_{n-1}\ +\ f(n)\ $which can be solved easily.